# Static files not getting loaded even in my Django admin page

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-staticfiles

I followed the below tutorial to create a Django blog application, but static files are not working even in admin page in production. In my local server everything is fine.

> https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/

I haven't added any static files to the application. my settings.py is below

```
"""
Django settings for jan_site project.
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.10.
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/
For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '******'
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['a.pythonanywhere.com']
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'jsite',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'jan_site.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'jan_site.wsgi.application'
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

I tried almost all solutions. If anyone can explain what is happening with admin static files please.

Comment: Is this running in production (on a server), or still in development on your laptop? If in production, did you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: If on your development machine, make sure you add the static urls to your urls.py as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) (wrap this in `if settings.DEBUG == True`)

Comment: running in production, already ran collectstatic

Answer (score 2):

If you are in development mode you need to add your static file root in your urlpatters. Reading [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

So in your main app's url file make sure you have added both.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: i deployed my application in pythonanywhere, the problem exists there only